# Exceed the 7 digit decimal limit for numeric values in R?

Tags: r

Just noticed that R limits numeric values to 7 digits below the decimal. I'm needing to calculate and output numeric values of down to 16 digits. Is it possible to exceed the supposed 7 digit decimal limit in R?

As you can see in the example below, it won't output
any digits below 7.

```
> 0.6431159420289856
[1] 0.6431159
```

Desired output of course is

```
> 0.6431159420289856
[1] 0.6431159420289856
```

My particular use case requires those values to be outputted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the decimal places displayed with `options(digits = 16)` to get your requested output.  That said, R will do math on all the digits available, regardless of the options setting for decimal places.

```
options(digits = 16)    
0.6431159420289856
[1] 0.6431159420289856
```

Comment: @srb633 happy to help.  If this answer solved your issue please accept it by clicking the checkmark